# I want to scroll down a page of CRM D365 form which is inside a container but cant locate it using selenium with python

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

syntax of layout of container:

```
 < div class = formContainer fill-width fill-height layout-container layout-vertical role="region" data-dyn-bind="
        attr: { 'aria-label': $dyn.format('{0}: {1}', $dyn.value($data.FormCaption), $dyn.value($data.ParentTitleFields)) },
        sizing: { width: $dyn.layout.Size.available, height: $dyn.layout.Size.available },
        layout: { arrangeMethod: $dyn.layout.ArrangeMethod.vertical }"
```

I tried using javascript executor for pycharm but this didnt work :
`self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")`